# Query to return zero rows with COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have seen a number of similar questions posted to StackOverflow and I haven't been successful in my attempts to apply them.

I would like to take an existing working `COUNT(*)` query and update it such that it also returns the rows with zero as the count value. I think that I need to use a `LEFT JOIN` but I'm not sure how to get it to work.

My current working query:

```
SELECT `VIC_HELMET_BELT`.`id`, `VIC_HELMET_BELT`.`HELMET_BELT` AS 'desc', COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM `VIC_ACCIDENT`, `VIC_NODE`, `VIC_PERSON`, `VIC_VEHICLE`, `VIC_HELMET_BELT` 
WHERE `VIC_NODE`.`ACCIDENT_NO` = `VIC_ACCIDENT`.`ACCIDENT_NO` 
AND `VIC_PERSON`.`ACCIDENT_NO` = `VIC_ACCIDENT`.`ACCIDENT_NO` 
AND `VIC_VEHICLE`.`ACCIDENT_NO` = `VIC_ACCIDENT`.`ACCIDENT_NO`
AND `VIC_PERSON`.`SEATING_POSITION_Id` = 1
AND `VIC_HELMET_BELT`.`id` = `VIC_PERSON`.`HELMET_BELT_WORN`
GROUP BY `VIC_HELMET_BELT`.`id`
```

This returns the table:

```
    id  desc                            count  
------  -----------------------------  --------
     1  Seatbelt worn                    390115
     2  Seatbelt not worn                 10158
     4  Child restraint not worn              1
     5  Seatbelt/restraint not fitted      1573
     6  Helmet worn                       60521
     7  Helmet not worn                    3495
     8  Not appropriate                    3635
     9  Not known                        168617
```

I would like the table to be returned with id=3 with a count of 0:

```
    id  desc                            count  
------  -----------------------------  --------
     1  Seatbelt worn                    390115
     2  Seatbelt not worn                 10158
     3  Child restraint worn                  0
     4  Child restraint not worn              1
     5  Seatbelt/restraint not fitted      1573
     6  Helmet worn                       60521
     7  Helmet not worn                    3495
     8  Not appropriate                    3635
     9  Not known                        168617
```

In case it's not clear from the query, `VIC_HELMET_BELT` is a lookup table that is equivalent to the `id` and `desc` columns of the table above. The `VIC_PERSONS.HELMET_BELT_WORN` contains the values I am counting that correspond to the `VIC_HELMET_BELT.id` values.

Any commentary on the quality of my original SQL is also appreciated. I feel like I never really had a strong understanding of how to make the most of SQL queries.

In case you're interested, this is crash data from Victoria, Australia. You may have noticed that I have filtered for the driver only. I really hope the "Child restraint not worn" entry is just a typo!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: oh yes, you should do `LEFT JOIN` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
SELECT `VIC_HELMET_BELT`.`id`, `VIC_HELMET_BELT`.`HELMET_BELT` AS 'desc', 
COUNT(`VIC_VEHICLE`.`ACCIDENT_NO`) AS 'count' 
FROM `VIC_HELMET_BELT`
  LEFT JOIN `VIC_PERSON` ON `VIC_HELMET_BELT`.`id` = `VIC_PERSON`.`HELMET_BELT_WORN` AND `VIC_PERSON`.`SEATING_POSITION_Id` = 1     
  LEFT JOIN `VIC_ACCIDENT` ON `VIC_PERSON`.`ACCIDENT_NO` = `VIC_ACCIDENT`.`ACCIDENT_NO`
  LEFT JOIN `VIC_NODE` on VIC_NODE`.`ACCIDENT_NO` = `VIC_ACCIDENT`.`ACCIDENT_NO`
  LEFT JOIN `VIC_VEHICLE` on `VIC_VEHICLE`.`ACCIDENT_NO` = `VIC_ACCIDENT`.`ACCIDENT_NO`    
GROUP BY `VIC_HELMET_BELT`.`id, `VIC_HELMET_BELT`.`HELMET_BELT`
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a `WHERE` clause and still get the zero row? For example: `WHERE VIC_VEHICLE.VEHICLE_ID = 'A'` or would I have to chain it within the `LEFT JOIN VIC_VEHICLE ON` line?

Comment: No, if you want to use the zero row, put the where directly on the left join like the way I did it for ` `VIC_PERSON`.`SEATING_POSITION_Id` = 1   `

Answer (score 0):

Try this query below and see if there's any count result for ID=3. If it's null, you can use `IFNULL(COUNT(*),0) AS 'Count'`:

```
SELECT `VIC_HELMET_BELT`.`id`, `VIC_HELMET_BELT`.`HELMET_BELT` AS 'desc', 
        COUNT(*) AS 'count' 
FROM `VIC_HELMET_BELT` 
LEFT JOIN  `VIC_PERSON` ON `VIC_HELMET_BELT`.`id` = `VIC_PERSON`.`HELMET_BELT_WORN`
LEFT JOIN  `VIC_ACCIDENT` ON `VIC_PERSON`.`ACCIDENT_NO` = `VIC_ACCIDENT`.`ACCIDENT_NO` 
LEFT JOIN  `VIC_NODE` ON `VIC_NODE`.`ACCIDENT_NO` = `VIC_ACCIDENT`.`ACCIDENT_NO` 
LEFT JOIN  `VIC_VEHICLE` ON `VIC_VEHICLE`.`ACCIDENT_NO` = `VIC_ACCIDENT`.`ACCIDENT_NO`
WHERE  `VIC_PERSON`.`SEATING_POSITION_Id` = 1
GROUP BY `VIC_HELMET_BELT`.`id`
```

As for the comment on your query, you can try using aliases on your table for shorter query .. example below:

```
SELECT v1.`id`, v1.`HELMET_BELT` AS 'desc', COUNT(*) AS 'count' 
FROM `VIC_HELMET_BELT` as v1
LEFT JOIN  `VIC_PERSON` as v2 ON v1.`id` = v2.`HELMET_BELT_WORN`
LEFT JOIN  `VIC_ACCIDENT` as v3 ON v2.`ACCIDENT_NO` = v3.`ACCIDENT_NO` 
LEFT JOIN  `VIC_NODE` as v4 ON v2.`ACCIDENT_NO` = v4.`ACCIDENT_NO` 
LEFT JOIN  `VIC_VEHICLE` as v5 ON v2.`ACCIDENT_NO` = v4`.`ACCIDENT_NO`
WHERE  v2.`SEATING_POSITION_Id` = 1
GROUP BY v1.`id`;
```

Each of your table being assigned with `v1, v2, v3 ...` and so on so that when you want to use a column from the table, you don't need to type the full table name instead you just need to type the alias.

**Edit:**Another way you can do is like this, assuming that you need to perform other operation on other tables except for `VIC_HELMET_BELT`; which just solely become a reference table.

```
SELECT v1.`id`, v1.`HELMET_BELT` AS 'desc', COUNT(*) AS 'count' 
FROM `VIC_HELMET_BELT` AS v1
LEFT JOIN  
(SELECT * FROM `VIC_PERSON` AS v2
INNER JOIN `VIC_ACCIDENT` AS v3 ON v2.`ACCIDENT_NO` = v3.`ACCIDENT_NO` 
INNER JOIN `VIC_NODE` AS v4 ON v2.`ACCIDENT_NO` = v4.`ACCIDENT_NO` 
INNER JOIN `VIC_VEHICLE` AS v5 ON v2.`ACCIDENT_NO` = v4.`ACCIDENT_NO`
WHERE v2.`SEATING_POSITION_Id` = 1) A
ON v1.`id`=A.`HELMET_BELT_WORN`
GROUP BY v1.`id`;
```

Comment: The full-length query returns the same table that I am already getting (without `id=3` row).

Comment: Must be the `WHERE` then... because with `WHERE  `VIC_PERSON`.`SEATING_POSITION_Id` = 1` , if the table `VIC_PERSON` doesn't have id=3, it will omit from the final output. Note that if your `WHERE` is from a table that doesn't contain any data from your most left table, it won't show it anyway. Effectively turning the `LEFT JOIN` to become `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: What you can do is separate the `VIC_HELMET_BELT` from the others and make a sub-query using them. Then you use `VIC_HELMET_BELT LEFT JOIN (your sub-query from other tables)`

Comment: It's not clear what he wants to get as a count. Depending on which count should be returned, he could probably get away with even a single left join without any other joins

Comment: I agree @mangusta . I'm always like this too. Sometimes I just need a simple query would suffice but I always end up with a huge one XD